# Wordpress 3.1 not autoupdating

Tags: automatic-updates

Hay All, when i run the auto-update for WordPress 3.1 it doesn't do anything.

It says

```
Downloading update from http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.1.zip…
Unpacking the update…
```

But then the browser stops, it leaves a 3 megabyte "wordpress-3.tmp" file in my wp-content folder.

Comment: try manually

Comment: turns out php's "safe mode" was an issue, having it on didn't allow the .zip file to decompress.

Comment: hi there,

i'm having the same problem - except i'm a complete noooob and don't know what php's safe mode is? any clues please?

Comment: @jules-whiteway It's a server setting that a host may use in the belief that it might make the server more secure. If you are having issues with updates check your web hosts FAQ's or ask if safe_mode is used on your server.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of this not haunting unanswered questions...

WordPress tries its best to deal with filesystem/permission issues [when updating](http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Automatic_Update) and requests access credentials if necessary.

So many issues in this department are more likely to be caused by hosting configuration, rather than WP itself. In this specific case [PHP safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php) was causing issues, which is not suprising given that it is deprecated feature, discouraged to be used by PHP developers.